# All OpenGL ES 2.0 functions return 79

Tags: android, opengl-es

No matter what I call all functions in OpenGL ES 2.0 return 79 if they return an int and null if they return a string. The device I am running on supports OpenGL ES 2.0, even sample code from the tutorial on the dev site will do this. Currently developing on Android 2.2(api level 8).  The application then simply draws the clear color. Have any of you seen this error cannot use glGetError as that returns 79 and only 79.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This can occur when `glGetError()` is called from outside the openGL thread.* (Other strange numbers can also be returned from `glGetError` for this reason)

This could likely occur if, say, in a GLSurfaceView, you are calling `glGetError()` from the constructor as opposed to the `onSurfaceCreated()` or `onDrawFrame()` functions.

Basically, it is returning garbage as opposed to a legitimate error.